# Azure Resource Group, cpu, dataio, logio missing when moved

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

We are running an azure SQL database on an old resource group with a not great name, so I wanted to move the databases to a new Resource group, when doing so it seems to all move ok, but we don't see any metrics information like CPU,Logio, Dataio for the databases
if I move it back to the original resource group that the metrics are shown there with no issues and even show the data when it was on new resource group.
I have tried looking metrics settings but does not make a difference, anyone got any ideas?

New resource group
[New Resource Group no data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTU7z.png)

old resource group
[Moved back to the old group seems fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4gBp.png)

The staging Database server we have I have managed to move around to different resource groups with no issues, just this one seems to an issue, I searched everywhere and no seen anyone else with the issue.
The only difference is that Production is hyperscale and staging is dtu

Comment: I asked Azure Support, please waiting the replay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted with Azure Support and they give me the answer:

The reason is Metrics provider is Microsoft.Insights, it doesn't support move resource group and subscription:

[image]

Reference: [microsoft.insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-support-resources#microsoftinsights).

When we move the SQL database to another resource group,  it will get a new resource ID and new Metric.

[image]

Screenshot:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: But the problem is it does not create a new metric, I left in a new resource group for hours and still nothing being shown, any chance you can ask microsoft :)

Comment: Hi @Earthcoder, I'm sorry that  my session with Azure Support is closed. You could [create a new Azure  Support  request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) with more details. Choose the Metrics service. In the end, [7/8/19 2:54 AM] Joy Wang (Shanghai Wicresoft Co,.Ltd.)
    

If my answer is helpful for you, please mark it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you very much!